# Any free plugin for magento elastic search

Tags: search, advanced-search

I am new to Magento and wanted to know, Is there any plugin/extension that will provide elastic search/live search feature and show result in product and category.

Comment: Review the extension 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/search-smartest-instant-search.html

Answer (score 2):

Check this plugin : https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

The demo is available here: http://demo.magento-elastic-suite.io/